# How do I "add a served file as a dependency" in my Karma configuration for an Angular 2 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, configuration, npm, karma-runner

I am trying to update an Angular 2 project by implementing the changes indicated in the official Angular 2 change log.

*(If you care to know the details, I completely worked through a tutorial that was built with Angular 2 version 2.0.0-beta.13 and want to now convert it to the current latest Angular, i.e. version 2.0.0-rc.6. The tutorial itself can be found on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMyduWydQv4) and the final code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/krsween/seek-starter).)*

I'm stuck at the following step: The [change log for Angular 2 version 2.0.0-beta.16](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26) states the following:

> You will also need to add the dependency 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js' as a served file in your Karma or other test configuration.

I'm not sure I completely understand what that means, and I don't see an obvious way to implement it. The `karma.conf.js` file for this project is the following:

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'source-map-support', 'jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test/init.js',
      'src/**/*.spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'test/init.js': ['browserify'],
      'src/**/*.spec.js': ['browserify']
    },


    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: ['babelify']
    },

    specReporter: {
        maxLogLines: 5,
        suppressErrorSummary: true,
        suppressFailed: false,
        suppressPassed: false,
        suppressSkipped: true,
        showSpecTiming: true
      },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['spec'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

I suspect the solution will involve a change to the above `karma.conf.js` file, but also possibly installation of an npm package, either through a command line `npm install ...` or, more likely, through modifying the dependencies in `package.json`. I don't know if this is relevant, but the tutorial's original (i.e. Ang2-beta.13) `package.json` lists `zone.js ^0.6.6` as a dependency while the change log for the most recent Angular2 (rc.6) lists `zone.js ^0.6.17` in its peer dependency updates.

Where have I looked? Well, I don't see an obvious place in this pre-existing config file for this new dependency to go, so I suspect that it might involve a configuration property not previously needed for this project. The [questions asked by `karma init`](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/configuration.html) seem too basic to be relevant. I have looked over the [complete list of karma configuration options](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html) and don't see an obvious place for this (and that page doesn't even contain the words "dependency" or "served"). I have also looked over the official Karma documentation for [files](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html) and [plugins](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/plugins.html) and neither provide an obvious solution.

So, how do I do what the change log mandates, i.e. how do I "add the dependency 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js' as a served file in [my] Karma ... configuration"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is probably embedded in the [change log for version rc.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/2.0.0-rc.5...2.0.0-rc.6). There, they state the following under "Breaking Changes": "testing config: due to zone.js peer-dependency upgrade, the order in which various zone specs are loaded has changed. Please see this example Karma config." That [example karma config](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16/karma.conf.js#L31-L38) shows the following:

```
config.set({
  files: [
    ...,
    // Reflect and Zone.js
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
    ...
  ],
  ...
});
```

I don't yet know how much of that list of dependencies is relevant, but at least it shows the syntax for including `fake-async-test.js`.

That's probably the best answer to my specific question. However, more generally, the linked example karma config file from the change log for version rc.6 is probably going to go a long way to helping me do the overall project update.